# Retrieve X11 window ID of a just-launched GUI-program

Tags: scripting, x11, process, window, wmctrl

I want to retrieve the X id of GUI programs I launch in background, in order to work on their windows properties. I've been so far using this workaround:

```
myprogram &
sleep 1
winID=$(wmctrl -l | awk '/./{line=$0} END{print $1;}')
```

But this relies on three heavy assumptions:

- the program will take less than 1 second to get its window opened (not to mention than 1 second can be far too long)
- the window will be appened at the end of the `wmctrl` list
- no other window will be opened meanwhile

Is there any signal `myprogram` will send once it has opened a window? How can I intercept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the Window ID in my program, I have the program set the title to something unique, then have the program start `wmctrl` and parse its output (and not the shell script that started the program), and then report on the Window ID (most often via a file).

Since the program doesn't continue until the windows are open, you will never have to wait to long.

This of course requires that you can change `myprogram` ( ie. compile from source).

Comment: This is still a workaround, isn't it? ;) (and rather heavy) I feel like there *is* something standard because Gnome, for example, kindly warns you when an application has been opened in background with a message like "** is ready". Is there an event dispatched any time a window opens? How to intercept it?

Comment: @Iago-lito Not sure what you call a workaround, you probably can ask X (via gnome) to get you the ID, but not AFAIK from outside the program. Parsing the output of wmctrl is just simpler. I don't know if there is a gnome event that you can catch, but by the time I check for the window title that I just set it is always there (or up to now it has always been there).

Comment: Okay, with "workaround" I meant this didn't sound so *straightforward*, but from what you say it seems like this depends much on the program itself. Let's go on with parsing the output of `wmctrl -l` then. Thank you by the way :) I'll still wait one day or so just in case someone has new insights into this. [EDIT]: argh! `can't vote you up yet.

Comment: In parsing the output of `wmctrl`, take care as there are porgrams that have titles without text etc. For my python based programs I use [ruamel.ewmh](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.ewmh) (shameless plug for my own stuff).

Comment: Gnome can do that because it's the window manager. The WM has special status in X, it gets notified of all window-related events. I don't think there's a way for other programs to get notified similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Using python gi library, (assuming that this program that has been launched most recently is on top of the window stack)

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Wnck', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Wnck , Gtk

screen=Wnck.Screen.get_default()
while Gtk.events_pending() :
    Gtk.main_iteration()

all_windows=screen.get_windows_stacked()

print(all_windows[0].get_xid())
```

PS. Not tested